# Python PEP 302 and __name__ attribute

Tags: python, import, namespaces, hook, ironpython

Currently i am creating a custom import hook, which seems to work pretty well (still under development). When i read the `PEP 302` i came accross the `__name__` attribute, which is descriped like this:

> The __name__ attribute must be set. If one uses imp.new_module() then the  attribute is set automatically.

But i don't get, whether name should contains the full path of the module/package or just it's name. For example when executing `import A.B` should `__name__` only contains `B` or the full path `A.B`?

Thank you very much!